# Como resuelvo el algoritmo de impresión de este examen en Java?

Tags: java

Me han tomado un examen de ingreso laboral, y tuve una duda en relación a una de las preguntas que me hicieron.
Este es el ejercicio completo, según su consigna.

Me podrían ayudar a entender que significan este punto que se encuentra en negrita por favor? y que quieren decir cuando me dice el punto, que solo debia cargar la lista de autos en un solo metodo?

Imaginemos una concesionaria de autos y motos.
Crear un programa cuyo punto de entrada sea un main en donde, al ejecutarse, se visualiza lo siguiente por consola y se termina la ejecución:

Marca: Peugeot // Modelo: 206 // Puertas: 4 // Precio: $200.000,00

Marca: Honda // Modelo: Titan // Cilindrada: 125c // Precio: $60.000,00

Marca: Peugeot // Modelo: 208 // Puertas: 5 // Precio: $250.000,00

Marca: Yamaha // Modelo: YBR // Cilindrada: 160c // Precio: $80.500,50

=============================

Vehículo más caro: Peugeot 208

Vehículo más barato: Honda Titan

Vehículo que contiene en el modelo la letra ‘Y’: Yamaha YBR $80.500,50

=============================

Vehículos ordenados por precio de mayor a menor:
Peugeot 208
Peugeot 206
Yamaha YBR
Honda Titan

La solución debe cumplir con los siguientes requisitos:

- Diseñar una solución orientada a objetos, creando por lo menos una clase abstracta y una interface.
- La salida es por consola y exactamente como se requiere.
- Usar solamente las clases provistas por Java 8.

**- Cargar la lista de autos en un único método. No hay ingreso por pantalla de ningún tipo.
- El algoritmo usado para la impresión no tiene que depender de la cantidad, modelo o tipo de autos**

```
public class ExamenVehiculos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Automoviles vehiculo206=new Automoviles("Peugeot", "206", 4, 200000);

        Motos vehiculoTitan=new Motos("Honda", "Titan", 125, 60000);

        Automoviles vehiculo208=new Automoviles("Peugeot", "208", 5, 250000);

        Motos vehiculoYBR=new Motos("Yamaha", "YBR", 160, 80500.50);

        public class Automoviles {

    public Automoviles(String marcaAutomovil, String modeloAutomovil, int puertas, double precioAutomovil) {

        this.marcaAutomovil=marcaAutomovil;

        this.modeloAutomovil=modeloAutomovil;

        this.puertas=puertas;

        this.precioAutomovil=precioAutomovil;

    }

    public String descripcion() {
        return marcaAutomovil;


    }

    private String marcaAutomovil;

    private String modeloAutomovil;

    private double precioAutomovil;

    private int puertas;


}




    }

}
```

```
public class Motos extends PrecioYDescripcion{

    public Motos(String marcaMoto, String modeloMoto, double cilindrada, double precioMoto) {

        this.marcaMoto=marcaMoto;

        this.modeloMoto=modeloMoto;

        this.cilindrada=cilindrada;

        this.precioMoto=precioMoto;

    }

    @Override
    public String marca() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return marcaMoto;
    }

    @Override
    public String modelo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return modeloMoto;
    }

    @Override
    public double precio() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return precioMoto;
    }

    public double cilindrada() {

        return cilindrada;
    }

    private String marcaMoto;

    private String modeloMoto;

    private double precioMoto;

    private double cilindrada;

}
```

```
public interface Vehiculos {

    String marca();

    String modelo();


}
```

```
public abstract class PrecioYDescripcion implements Vehiculos{

    public abstract double precio();

    public String Descripcion() {

        return null;


    }


}
```

Comment: hay un metodo cargar autos en la clase que sea que carga toda esa lista. No entiendo muy bien la pregunta... es un ejercicio, no tiene que ser logico...

Comment: ¿y tu código dónde quedó?

Comment: Ahi subo el codigo! y que significa El algoritmo usado para la impresión no tiene que depender de la cantidad, modelo o tipo de autos

Comment: Bueno, tienes dos clases hijas y necesitas al padre (la clase Vehiculo). Como sabrás, las clases hijas heredan los métodos del padre. Lo que yo creo que te pide, es que hagas la lista de vehículos (coches y motos) que serán hijos de la clase Vehículo (es decir, necesitarás un array de vehiculos). Una vez les tengas a todos juntos ya será fácil operar con ellos. Por lo pronto en tu clase abstracta yo recopilaría todos los vehículos. Una vez los tengas ya puedes saber toda la información que quieras sobre ellos, los métodos que implementes a partir de ahí usarán tu nueva lista. (Será más fácil)

Comment: @adrian Gracias! Es lo que yo pensaba! Con un array y un for, y las 2 Claes hijo estaría bien. Perdón por la pregunta, que quisiste decir con "en tu clase abstracta yo recopilará todos los vehículos", a que te refers con recopilar? Gracias!!!!!

Comment: Quiero decir, que el método que te piden de tener la lista de Motocicletas y Coches yo le haría allí. Allí es donde vas a poder tener la mezcla. Tu método getVehiculos() que es el que te piden estará en tu clase Vehiculo.

Comment: Gracias Genio!!!